# Непонятный синтаксис с двумя именами в typedef

Tags: c, typedef, union

```
typedef union {  
    char word[16];  
    uint32_t chunk[4];  
    uint64_t big_chunk[2];  
} Word, *PWord;   // <-- Что означают эти два имени?
```

Comment: О чем именно идет речь?

Comment: последняя строчка не понятна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да хоть с десятью именами. Как и [почти] любое объявление в С, typedef-объявление может объявлять несколько идентификаторов сразу

```
const int a, *b, *const *c, d[5], e(void);

// эквивалентно

const int a;
const int *b;
const int *const *c;
const int d[5];
const int e(void);
```

Точно так же

```
typedef int a, *b, *const *c, d[5], e(void);

// эквивалентно

typedef int a;
typedef int *b;
typedef int *const *c;
typedef int d[5];
typedef int e(void);
```

Именно это и используется в вашем объявлении.

То, что в объявлении фигурирует `union`, тут никакой принципиальной роли не играет. Если бы у вашего `union` был указан тэг (скажем, `W`), то можно было разбить ваше объявление на три отдельных объявления

```
union W {  
    char word[16];  
    uint32_t chunk[4];  
    uint64_t big_chunk[2];  
};

typedef union W Word;
typedef union W *PWord;
```

Comment: можете пожалуйста пояснить что мы создаём тут                               char* buffer = new char [WORD_SIZE];
        PWord word = (PWord) buffer;

Answer (score 2):

Объявлены: `Word` - тип объединения, `PWord` - тип указателя на объединение.

Вас это интересовало?